# CSS How to keep submenu items inside wrapper

Tags: html, css

```css
#wrapper {
  max-width: 1440px;
  position: relative;
  background: #999;
  z-index: 1;
}

.base-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: calc(100% + 32px);
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: -16px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.base-list>* {
  flex: 0 0 calc(25% - 32px);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 16px;
}

.base-list div a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: white;
  padding: 24px;
}

.extended-card {
  margin-top: 32px;
  width: calc(100vw - 32px);
}

.w-edge {
  margin-left: -50vw;
  margin-right: -50vw;
}

.items {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.extended-card .base-list div a {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="base-list">
    <div>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <div class="w-edge extended-card">
        <div class="items base-list">
          <a href="#">Sublink 1</a>
          <a href="#">Sublink 2</a>
          <a href="#">Sublink 3</a>
          <a href="#">Sublink 4</a>
          <a href="#">Sublink 5</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#">Link 5</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have this odd thing, that the submenu items of my horizontal menu don't stay inside the wrapper. Basically the subitems should appear under the clicked parent item but for some reason, as mentioned before, they do not stay inside the wrapping element at all.

I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hbc462w0/1/) for this, where the scenario is, when Link 2 is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever they are supposed to do, I would remove that .w-edge class and the width property of that .extended-card class. It will work then.

Comment: This doesn't work, since the submenu items should fill out the entire width of the wrapping container....